# Echo RUN step while docker build

Tags: docker

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12.19
RUN echo aaaaa
```

and want to see the output of the `echo` command on `docker build . --progress=plain`
but the output doesn't appear.

Comment: Please include the output you do see in your question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Period (.) must come at the end..

```
docker build --progress=plain .
```

See usage [docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/)

2. Add double quotes to the statement to be printed - best practice

```
FROM node:12.19
RUN echo aaaaa
```

To

```
FROM node:12.19
RUN echo "aaaaa"
```

Tested on docker version: 20.10.0
Prints:

```
...
Step 2/2 : RUN echo "aaaaa"
  ----> Running in ca5fb7181414
aaaaa
Removing intermediate container ca5fb7181414
...
```

Full O/P:
[image: Output image]

Comment: Neither of these should make a difference. The context path traditionally comes at the end but can appear earlier in the command. And the quoting around a string is optional if you don't have special characters.

Comment: I'll be happy to remove my downvote if you show the test case with the dot moved before the flag, and the quotes missing, with the errors matching what the OP saw.

Comment: I agree to both the points, it doesn't fail when OP's command is being run. @programista5k Please include more details like docker version ?